# Is there standard Rails mechanism to concat all javascript files into public/javascripts/cache/all.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

If the file `public/javascripts/cache/all.js` is removed, and then a webpage is fetched from the rails server, then that `all.js` file
magically reappears in the file system, with a timestamp that is half an hour ago.  Is there actually Rails mechanism that regenerates this file 
or what might be regenerating this file?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're using `javascript_include_tag :all, :cache => true` somewhere in your layout.
This will bundle all of your javascripts into `all.js`. You can also use `:recursive => true` to include subdirectories.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag